# Dynamically changing the text on an UIApplicationShortcutItem

Tags: ios, ios9, uiapplication, 3dtouch

I implemented two dynamic "Home screen quick actions" as UIApplicationShortcutItem in my rootViewController- just like Apple suggests in [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplicationShortcutItem/).
This works like a charm.

My problem is, I would like to change the text of my titles and subtitles without entering the app, just like the application badge does.
Specifically, I would like my subtitle text to represent the number 
`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber`.

The problem is, my subtitle is only updated when the user enters the app, not automatically like with the badge. How do I push an updated string and refresh my subtitle? Is this at all possible?

Thanks in advance.